# accessing browser audio codecs for encoding

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

from the docs ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData)):

> The decodeAudioData() method of the BaseAudioContext Interface is used to asynchronously decode audio file data contained in an ArrayBuffer.

```
ctx.decodeAudioData(audioData).then(function(decodedData) {
 // use the decoded data here
});
```

My question is can we access the browser's audio codecs in order to perform encoding instead of decoding (i.e. convert raw pcm  -> flac/opus/mp3 etc..)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not yet possible. There is currently a proposal for a new API or a set of APIs called [WebCodecs](https://github.com/WICG/web-codecs) which may support that use case in the future.

Until then the only native way I could think of to encode audio would be using the `MediaRecorder`. But it can't be used to accurately encode an `AudioBuffer` since it's `start()` and `stop()` methods are not precise.